# How do I chosse row array that above 10 in Python?

Tags: python

I have information below:

```
name=['Ali', 'Reza']
math=[10,12]
stat=[14,15]
comp=[8,14]
```

I want to give False or True, if the three scores are above ten,indeed:
I can build output below:

```
'pass':[False, True]
```

Answer (score 1):

1. You can use `zip` to get list of grades for one person

   ```
   zip(math, stat, comp) => [(10, 14, 8), (12, 15, 14)]
   ```
2. Then check that `all` are `>10`

   ```
   result = [all(grade > 10 for grade in grades) for grades in zip(math, stat, comp)]
   print(result) # [False, True]
   ```

---

To get a dict `name:pass` you can add the `name` in the zip and handle it as a key

```
result = {grades[0]: all(x > 10 for x in grades[1:]) for grades in zip(name, math, stat, comp)}
print(result)  # {'Ali': False, 'Reza': True}
```

Comment: Thanks for you, i want out put below:{'Name':['ali','reza'], 'Ave': [10.67, 13.67], 'pass':[False, True]}

Comment: @farshadsobhani Did you try to ?

Comment: thank you, i want exactly out put below: `{'Name':['ali','reza'], 'Ave': [10.67, 13.67], 'pass':[False, True]}`

Comment: @farshadsobhani i undersood first time. But did you try to do it ? Maybe I souldn't have answer so fast now you think Stackoverflow is a coding service , are you learning python ? If yes you need to pratice to improve yourself

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np
def p(name,math,stat,comp):
    data={}
    n=len(name)
    arr1=np.array([math,stat,comp])
    arr2=arr1.mean(axis=0)
    arr2=np.around(arr2,2)
    list1=list(arr2)
    result = {grades[0]: all(x > 10 for x in grades[1:]) for grades in zip(name, math, stat, comp)}
    g=result.values()
    h=list(g)
    data={'name':name,'Ave': list1,'Pass':h}
    print(data)
```

## Example:

```
name=['Ali', 'Reza']
math=[10,12]
stat=[14,15]
comp=[8,14]
```

```
p(name,math,stat,comp)
```

output:

```
{'name': ['Ali', 'Reza'], 'Ave': [10.67, 13.67], 'Pass': [False, True]}
```